# Request module with nodejs to POST

Tags: node.js, request, node-modules

Trying to create a api with request module which could be called from curl etc.
can you help to check if am doing any wrong here

```
request({
        url: 'http:asdasd/testapi',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
        body: {
        'id':1,
        'name':'xxxx'
        },
        json: true
    }, function (error, result, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else if (result.statusCode === 500) {
            console.log('error');
        } else {
            console.log(body);
        }
    });
```

**Error**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /testapi</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your url is wrong.

Comment: thanks , that was just sample this is the url format , let me know if this is incorrect

http://<host fqdn>:<port>/testapi

Comment: I think the url is unreachable or doesn't have POST api.